# Can I use a public / private keypair to secure traffic on my wifi on OpenWRT?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, wireless

Wifi passwords are a pretty weak way to secure a Wifi Access point; is it possible to use a public / private key to secure traffic on a wifi access point which runs OpenWRT.

I know I can secure SSH with one, but what about the traffic on my access point?

Comment: you want EAP-TLS with client certificates (signed by your self-signed CA). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol#EAP_Transport_Layer_Security_(EAP-TLS) and https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/encryption#configure_wpa2_enterprise_eap-tls_with_external_radius_server

Comment: wpa2 with a good entropy password is not weak.